# Adding one more feature to my feature set which has no effect in calculation and act as a distiguishable feature

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a of problem as follow:

I have 10000 thousand of tweets and and I have some features which are labeled 1 or 2 . I wanna add another feature but the problem is exactly here:

I want to give each tweet (a feature)a unique id according the user who posted that tweet, so if a user posted 3 posts these 3 posts will get the same id since the same user posted them this way I can be more sure in classifying these tweets in the same group since I can claim that if most of these tweets are assigned the same label the newly coming tweet will be more probable to be in the same group.Also I am using decision tree and naive Bayes now my question is that does it make sense to do so since this feature is not numeric and has no effect in calculation and it acts as a dummy feature which is just used for distinguishing tweets?

Comment: 1. If you're adding an ID, then it is (or should be) numeric; 2. If you're adding a feature, it will have **some** effect in your calculations. Whether or not it makes sense for your task is impossible to say without knowing what the task is, and even then, the best thing you can do is test and find out.

Comment: @IVlad Why should the ID be numeric? He's talking about a user ID, not tweet/record ID. A numeric feature would imply an order between the users, which does not make a lot of sense. I'd say numeric or not does not matter as it would be better to have it as a categorical variable (Of course it might not be practical to do something else than integer encoding depending on the number of different users).

Comment: What are you trying to do here; predict user ids given the other features? If so, the user id feature will have a tremendous effect on calculation. Can you clarify your research task?

Comment: @duhaime I am trying to seeif the text is sarcastic or not

Comment: I see, so your traing data has some labelled groundtruth values that indicate whether a text is sarcastic, and you want to train your model using some of those observations and evaluate model accuracy by using a held out sample of labelled data? If so, I wouldn't feed the author id's to the model, but would use them after running the analysis to determine which aithors were most/least sarcastic.